# completion of a pre-Hilbert sapce

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Suppose $S,T$ are two pre-Hilbert spaces and $S$ is dense in $T$.After completions of $S$ and $T$,we get two Hilbert spaces $\bar{S}$ and $\bar{T}$,is $\bar{S}=\bar{T}$? On the other hand,$S$ is dense in T,does it mean $\bar{S}=T$,I always confuse the "closure"  and the "completion",I'll appreciate it if anyone who could interpret these two concepts.Thanks

Comment: $S$ dense in $T$ does not mean $\bar {S}=T$.  In fact $S$ could $=T$ initially.

Comment: What is the precise definition of a dense set?

Comment: @herb steinberg  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_set

Comment: The definition is s little confusing.  Can a set be dense in itself?

Answer (score 1):

As sets, the completions $\overline S$ and $\overline T$ are not the same (recall how the completion of a metric space if defined).  But as Hilbert spaces, they are isomorphic.

Let $\iota:S\to T$ be the inclusion, and let $j:T\to\overline T$ be the canonical injection.  Then $j\circ\iota:S\to\overline T$ is a linear isometry with dense image, hence extends to a surjective linear isometry (i.e. a unitary) $\overline S\to \overline T$.